# how to provide different color background on selected/unselected item on dropdown css

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, css-selectors

I have one dropdown menu with multiple option that I would like to provide different color background on selected or unselected options the only way I can think is provide logic under className. It seems fine but I am wondering if any clean way for me to do it?thinking about using `classNames` from 'classnames' library but cannot figure out how I can provide variable

```
//src
import "./styles.css";

export enum LabelsEnum {
  HOME = 0,
  SCHOOL = 1,
  PARK = 2
}

const labels: string[] = ["Home", "School", "Park"];
const activeLabel = 1;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {labels.map((_, idx) => {
          const itemClass = classNames({
            "item-selected": activeLabel === idx,
            "item-unselected": activeLabel === idx
          });
          if (idx === LabelsEnum.HOME) {
            return (
              <li
                key={idx}
                role="option"
                className={`item-${
                  activeLabel === idx ? "selected" : "unselected"
                }`}
                aria-selected={activeLabel === idx}
              >
                Home
              </li>
            );
          }
          return (
            <li
              key={idx}
              role="option"
              className={`item-${
                activeLabel === idx ? "selected" : "unselected"
              }`}
              aria-selected={activeLabel === idx}
            >
              Park
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
//styles.css
.item-selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your solution works than that's good and you can keep it that way. As I looked at your code a saw the aria-selected attribute and had the idea that you could also use the css attribute selector to save some code:

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        p[aria-selected] {
        background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p aria-selected="true">hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in your case you would just do it like this:

```
//src
import "./styles.css";

export enum LabelsEnum {
  HOME = 0,
  SCHOOL = 1,
  PARK = 2
}

const labels: string[] = ["Home", "School", "Park"];
const activeLabel = 1;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {labels.map((_, idx) => {
          if (idx === LabelsEnum.HOME) {
            return (
              <li
                key={idx}
                role="option"
                aria-selected={activeLabel === idx}
              >
                Home
              </li>
            );
          }
          return (
            <li
              key={idx}
              role="option"
              selected={activeLabel === idx}
            >
              Park
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
//styles.css
li[aria-selected] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Doing it like this saves you the classes, but your solution is completely fine too.